# Status bar and toolbar equal to the Android chat

Tags: android

How do I make the toolbar the same as Android chat? That is white and also the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

you can try ` if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

```
        activity.getWindow()
                          .setStatusBarColor(          
                           ContextCompat.getColor(activity, color)
                           );
   }`
```